# Serverless or Trigger based processing in Databricks spark application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have been working on a use case where we receive messages in the event hub/kafka topic and the rate at which we receive is very less at the rate of 5 to 10 events per hour.

Is there any serverless compute available in Databricks (Not the SQL one), which will bring up the computing cluster to process those 4 to 5 events and go back to a dormant state?

I dont want to keep a streaming job up and running - 24x7 for just 4-5 events getting processed in an hour. Also, batch mode won't work - as it runs on a schedule. Is there a Databricks service/functionality which can come up from sleep, process those 4 or 5 events, and go back to sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of right now there is no serverless compute (outside of SQL & model serving) available for use by customers (but it's [coming](https://www.databricks.com/blog/whats-new-data-engineering-and-streaming-data-ai-summit-2023)).  Also, Databricks doesn't support trigger based on the data in message bus, it only support scheduled run or so-called [file arrival triggers](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/file-arrival-triggers.html).  But you can setup a [EventHubs capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview) for your topic and this may trigger jobs when file(s) are created (there is a setting in file arrival trigger that could allow to limit a one job/hour).